# CollectionView OrderBy

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uicollectionview

Hi I am using a horizontal sliding (pagination) `collectionView`. I am getting this data from my server on Parse so I am unable to organize this data on the website. The code I have below works with a `tableView` but how would I be able to translate this to a CollectionView? Thank you!!

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

//    [query orderByAscending:@"name"];

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is part of `PFQueryTableViewController`, a tableview subclass that Parse created to make it easier to display info in a tableview. However, the line `[query orderByAscending:@"name"];` is not specific to that class, you can use that on any query. I would suggest adding a query to your collection view, ordering it how you wish, and displaying it in the collection. I don't think you should use the PFQTVC as it is meant to be used with tables.